# Azure functions - function.json where is it located?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I can see all over the net that bindings are configured in the function.json file. I have created a Azure Function project in Visual Studio, and I can see the file is generated in the out folder. But it is not part of my project. Is the idea, that you add it to your local.settings.json file, and then visual studio takes it from there to generate the file (including the deployment)? Or where should I add the bindings? Seems kind of strange, I would expect the local.settings.json to be a file that dosent get deployed to Azure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using compiled C# class library functions, the build process creates `function.json` (look in the bin directory)

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library#functions-class-library-project

> The build process creates a function.json file for each function. This function.json file is not meant to be edited directly. You can't
>   change binding configuration or disable the function by editing this
>   file. To learn how to disable a function, see How to disable
>   functions.

Bindings are configured using attributes ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-triggers-bindings))

```
[FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]                    
public static void Run(
    [ServiceBusTrigger("myqueue", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] 
    string myQueueItem,
    Int32 deliveryCount,
    DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc,
    string messageId,

    [Blob("sample-images-md/{name}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "StorageConnectionAppSetting")] Stream outputBlob)

    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
    log.LogInformation($"EnqueuedTimeUtc={enqueuedTimeUtc}");
    log.LogInformation($"DeliveryCount={deliveryCount}");
    log.LogInformation($"MessageId={messageId}");

    //now store something to outputBlob
}
```

`StorageConnectionAppSetting` is defined in config. For local, that's local.settings.json

Comment: Thanks. Thats what I state in my post too. My question is, where do I then configure the binding? It would be pretty cumbersome to configure the generated file after each build.

Comment: What binding? What kind of triggered function are you creating?

Comment: Its triggered by a service bus. Now I want to add a out trigger that writes to blobstorage. But I dont know where to add the bindings of the out blob trigger. As stated the function.json is generated. Should I add it to the local.settings.json or which file?

Comment: No, you should add the attribute - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus

ServiceBus trigger, Blob storage output
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output

I've updated my example in the answer

Comment: Ahh so I just have to attributes and the function.json will be generated from that.

Comment: @ThomasSegato yes, exactly - just ignore the `function.json` if you're using class libraries (rather than csharp script) - you don't need to worry about it, it gets generated for you

Comment: Got it! Thanks I focus on the attribute part. Thanks alot!

Comment: One last question :D So in the documentation you link to following sample is used. [Blob("sample-images-sm/{name}", FileAccess.Write)] Stream imageSmall, Where do you tell the fucntion which storage account to write to? There is a missing link here?

Comment: See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob#output---configuration
I've updated the example again

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for it but using the web portal (portal.azure.com)
and finally, find it :

**From homepage -> select created Function app -> on left menu select Functions -> select your trigger -> then check m screen shoot**

[image]

the surprise is: ***you have a dropdown to change the file*** :) it's an amazing UX

Thanks Microsoft

Answer (score 1):

I'm using python and when you create a new project from the vscode Azure extension, it's crucial to select model v1 when you do the setup in order to get a function.json file. If you select model v2 there's no function.json file and you won't be able to select several Azure templates when you want to add a new function to your app.

In the workspace local tab, click the lightning icon and click:
Create New Project
Set or select the following items in the setup:

1. Select the local folder for the project
2. Language: Python
3. Model V1 → Important!
4. Python interpreter: 3.10 (matching version is 3.10.4)
5. Template: HTTP trigger
6. Authorization level: FUNCTION
7. Create new Insights monitor

Comment: I am not sure if this is really relevant to the initial question. Helpful, but not relevant.

Comment: @JeffB The missing function.json file is the reason I landed on this page in the first place as it was missing for me too. The OP didn't provide the language he was using and the top answer refers to C# only. Since I'm using Python and that solution didn't apply to me, I figured I'd add the solution for a missing function.json file for that environment as well.

Comment: no worries! The question is tagged with `C#`, but your answer is still useful. It maybe worth making your own question and posting a self answer with the proper tags to refer to python.